# How to join a column from another table to a new table you wish to display

Tags: sql, sql-server, count, inner-join

I am currently working on a database where I am trying to find all the transactional type tables (where the table name does not start with _Result or _ History) in the database and then display how many times each table is used in a calculation for the database model.

The purpose of finding out this is to determine the most important tables in the calculation, so that these certain tables will have a priority when updating statistics.

There are currently two tables I am working with.
1) The first table called tmpCalcSources shows the name for all the source tables in the database (Column called 'Source') along with the Calculation ID (Column called 'CalculationID') associated with it
2) The second table called tmpCalcSourceRows shows the source table name (Column called 'TableName') as well as the amount of rows associated with each source table (Column called 'RowNum')

I currently have this query:

SELECT Source,

COUNT(CalculationID) AS NumberOfUses

FROM tmpCalcSources

WHERE Source not like '%_Result%'

GROUP BY Source

ORDER BY NumberOfUses DESC;

The above query provides me with the following table:

plPeriods              292

plMeasures             10

Time                         43

etc...

I am now trying to add one more thing to the above table. I want it to also show the number of rows contained in each table (so a another column). I would like to take the column 'RowNum' from tmpCalcSourceRows table and be able to display that in the table shown above.

Comment: I don't think your data is correct. That query should not result in that table. Sum(1) will count the number of rows that your query groups together, but I don't know if that will help because I don't understand what you are asking.

Comment: I dont understand everything, but you can split your query into two separate Common Table Expression and than make a simple join.

Comment: Did you pivot the results from your query and drop the column labels? Otherwise the results from your query don't match the query you provided. What's the name of the other table? Are you saying that this other table can be joined using the column TableName with tmpCalcSources.Source?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for:

```
select
  Source
, NumberOfUses
, numberofrows
from (
    SELECT Source,COUNT(CalculationID) AS NumberOfUses
    FROM tmpCalcSources
    WHERE Source not like '%_Result%'
    GROUP BY Source
    ) tableUses
    join numRowsTable on numRowsTable.TableName=tableUses.Source
ORDER BY NumberOfUses DESC;
```

Comment: Yes this query worked well, it added the numberofrows column to what I wanted to be displayed. 
I received however a table showing this:
plPeriods 292 104
plPeriods 292 104
plPeriods 292 104
plMeasures 200 147
plMeasures 200 147
plMeasures 200 147

The information is correct, however the source names are being repeated for some reason.

Comment: It seems its displaying the Source Name row the same amount of times the CalculationID value is, which is 292 for plPeroids.